# How we handle questions about feature requests and bugs

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, design

I was surprised to find a custom off-topic choice (when filing to close a question) for bugs and feature requests

> Questions about bugs and feature requests are off-topic because they cannot be resolved via Q&A. For more information on how to report issues, see How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?

(Meaning that these items are not handled on the site.) I haven't seen this discussed elsewhere but I both agree and disagree with this. On one hand, if something is a bug and we have no other recourse for a brief or permanent fix recommendation, yes, it's definitely better [filed at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug). And on the other hand, sometimes a user (or we) don't know whether something is a bug/intentional or whether someone will have a surprise recommendation that makes the Q&A worth it. These are easy enough to triage, though, if only by discretion of what will be more productive centralized on Launchpad. This said, the SE interface does not do a good job of directing bug/feature reports to Launchpad, so it's only after someone invests time in signing up and posting that we someone rudely "close" their question and ask them for more time in reposting to Launchpad.

So, **can we request that the guiding details next to the Question field be modified** to some other text? Perhaps something about how we handle questions relating to elementary OS but that bug reports and feature requests are better handled at Launchpad (link to site)?

Comment: Ideally there would also be a way to import the question details into a bug report at the click of a single link once a question has been closed as a bug/feature (move to Launchpad)